Please add a character count for the private note edit boxes on the Save to dialog for saves
It is possible to create a private note when saving a post to a Saves list and this private note can be up to 500 characters long.
However, at the moment, there is no indication how many characters you have typed and there is no indication how close you are to the limit or how many characters you are over the limit.
The only information you are given is a warning message when you try to save a private note telling you that you have exceeded the limit:

Similarly for editing a private note from the listing of a saves list.
Please therefore add a character count to private note edit boxes, similar to the character count for adding a comment, for example:



Yeah this is pretty trivial, and already exists in most, if not all, other places where length is limited: comments, custom flags, even chat, where there's no counter but it does tell you when you're over the limit.

@ShadowWizard Yes, it would also be nice if the edit box on the dialog could be extendable by dragging and the edit box under the post to be multi-line like all the other edit boxes. But I think that might have already been feature requested.

Ah! I didn't even notice, but yeah, the core "issue" is actually the different element. Comments, custom flags, chat - all of those have <textarea> element, which is indeed multi-line input. However, the Saves private note has, for some odd reason "only" an <input> element, which is meant for single line of text, so using such logic, there's indeed no point in characters count, e.g. same as the search input box. So a better request would be changing the Saves private note box to multi-line textbox, like in the other places that can get, well, more than one line.
